# Form implementation not working

Tags: php, validation, forms, contact-form

I've made a simple form with PHP verification but actually, I got stuck in a matter as I'm not a pro which is not been sorted out, the details are given below:

**Form HTML:**

```
<div class="formbx">
    <h2 class="git text-center" style="margin-top: 5px;">GET IN <span style="color: #ff3600;">TOUCH</span></h2>
    <div class="frmer ">
        <form action="contacts.php" method="POST" name="contactform">
            <input id="txtexpName" style="border: none; margin-bottom: 15px; height: 30px; width: 100%; padding-left: 55px;" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" />
            <div class="txtexpPhoneCntr">
                <input id="txtexpPhone" style="border: none; margin-bottom: 15px; height: 30px; width: 100%; padding-left: 85px;" maxlength="10" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
            </div>
            <input id="txtexpEmail" style="border: none; margin-bottom: 15px; height: 30px; width: 100%; padding-left: 55px;" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" /> 
            <input id="txtexpCity" style="border: none; margin-bottom: 15px; height: 30px; width: 100%; padding-left: 55px;" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your City" /> 
            <textarea id="txtexpQuery" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            <button id="send" name="send" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <div class="loading"> </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            <label id="ErrorMsgExp" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none; padding: 4px;"></label> 
            <label id="SuccessMsgExp" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none; padding: 4px;">Thank you for your interest.</label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$formcontent=" Someone Contacted. Here are the details: \n Name: $name \n Mobile Number: $phone \n Email: $email \n City: $city \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "webdesigndevil0@gmail.com";
$subject = "Someone Contacted From Your Website";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='contact' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff3600;'> Return Home</a>";

?>
```

Upon submission of the form showing "Error", I'm not getting it where it causing an error, is there any syntax error?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Actually, upon submission of the form, a blank page opening with the text ERROR. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You used this name attribute twice: `name="name"` (second time in the "txtexpCity" input tag). Should be `name="city"` the second time...

Comment: Thanks for your quick lookup and help. Trying, would get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, tried/changed the "name" option but in vain, showing the same error. Thank you.

Comment: Hi #Johannes, is there anything that you can come up to assist me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like php's mail function is giving the error. You can debug it. Use the error_get_last() function to get the error.

```
$successfulMail = mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
if (!$successfulMail) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['formcontent'];
}
```

You can also just do a print_r(error_get_last()).

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

Please share the error with us so we can help you.

Comment: Hi Tim, tried the process you mentioned but really it's not working, after clicking the submit button opening a blank page instead of the Thank You message. Thank you.